# How I get Json value in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I can't get the Json value.

I wright like the following.

React.js

```
  const arm = sensor.filter(c => c.object_id === object_id).map((sensor_item, i) => { return {sensor_item}});
  console.log(arm)  //63 index
  console.log(arm[0]) //64 index
```

I got this response like the photo(Chrome console).

Like the picture below
You can see that the value of armed in arm[0] contains the information "true"
[image]

but I wright like this

```
 const arm = sensor.filter(c => c.object_id === object_id).map((sensor_item, i) => { return {sensor_item}});
  console.log(arm)
  console.log(arm[0])
  console.log(arm[0].sensor_item)
```

I got the error like photo below...
I don't know why...
[image]

Comment: Is `sensor` empty at one point (during initialisation for example)? You'll notice it also prints `[]` in the screenshot, indicating that the filter/map cant find what you need.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know why [] is empty. As you can see the first photo, there is console.log(arm) and console.log(arm[0) result...

Comment: Are there any log lines before that indicating `[]` and `undefined`? It may have to do with asynchronous operations, but its hard to tell without the rest of the code.